# Why "this." is not working in my .js file?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm confused because my .js file can't read: `this.innerHTML`

I couldn't find an answer od that?

```
   var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;

        switch (buttonInnerHTML) {
          case "w":
            (var audio = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3"); audio.play();
              break;

              case "a":
              (var audio = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3"); audio.play();
                break;

                case "s":
                (var audio = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3"); audio.play();
                  break;

                  case "d":
                  (var audio = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3"); audio.play();
                    break;

                    case "j":
                    (var audio = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3"); audio.play();
                      break;

                      case "k":
                      (var audio = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3"); audio.play();
                        break;

                        case "l":
                        (var audio = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3"); audio.play();
                          break;

                          default: console.log(buttonInnerHTML);

                        }


                      });

                  }
```

as far as I know this. is supposed to be colored in red, but it's not, therefore the function doesn't work.

I attached a screenshot down below
[image: 1]

Comment: Screenshot is missing

Comment: here is no screenshot .Please post your code too

Comment: could you press F12 and check console errors

Comment: Any error that is being thrown?

Comment: Please add code instead of a screenshot

Comment: no errors. it just doesn't work

Comment: it would be helpful if you could also share your html code. that way people can test your code. also instead of a screenshot, copy and paste your code here and use stackoverflows code feature (look for the {} button in your editor)

Comment: "_this. is supposed to be colored in red_" What is supposed to colored in red? There's nothing color specific in the code using the variable.

Comment: The code as shown would result in a syntax error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'` due to the `(` in front of `var audio =`

Comment: I formatted your code and removed the ( in front of every `var audio`

Comment: @CBroe the OP expects that `this` refers to the clicked element. And that's the case. It is not about a different `this`.

Comment: @mplungjan and what if those `(` are the actual reason for the problem?

Comment: Then it can be closed as a typo-type question and we can all go home

Comment: haha thank you guys! that was stupid. so sorry for bothering you!

Comment: @mplungjan sure, but I don't think that such a change is helpful, so either it should be clarified if  `(` is the problem or not.  Because `this` within an event handler would refer to the object it is attached to, so it is more likely that the reason is the typo. Due to your change, the question now gives the impression that `this.innerHTML` does not work for some reason.

Comment: I believe, document.querySelectorAll function returns an live array of elements, and I don't think you can use addEventListener on an array because isn't a method of the array type.  Instead, you need to iterate over the individual array elements in some fashion, but even so, the this hidden parameter is kind of tricky and most likely is 'pointing' to window, but this depend on how you iterate over the elements.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for more details.

Comment: @t.niese <sigh> By all means...

Comment: @HowardBrown And what is this then `for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function()` it will have `this` as the drum element

Comment: instead of this try document .getElementById("id").innerHTML

Comment: mplungjan, According to the addElementListener method documentation, function gets the event as it's sole parameter, but yes, it also gets this, and I misspoke about the this is this case, you're correct within the function, this does point to the div.drum element that was clicked.  I usually just use the event to get the clicked element, but using this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spurious `(` in front of all your var audio.

If you press F12 you will see console errors.

Normally this.innerHTMLm should work as you are using function in the eventListener

But you get `document.querySelectorAll(".drum")` in each iteration  - that is not optimal

Delegation is MUCH cleaner

I assume all drums are in a static container with ID=drumContainer

```js
const drums = {
  "w": "sounds/tom-1.mp3",
  "a": "sounds/tom-2.mp3",
  "s": "sounds/tom-3.mp3",
  "d": "sounds/tom-4.mp3",
  "j": "sounds/snare.mp3",
  "k": "sounds/crash.mp3",
  "l": "sounds/kick-bass.mp3"
};

document.getElementById("drumContainer").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("drum")) {
    const audio = new Audio(drums[tgt.textContent]);
    audio.play();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[MDN: The value of `this` within the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler)

> It is often desirable to reference the element on which the event handler was fired, such as when using a generic handler for a set of similar elements.
>
> If attaching a handler function to an element using `addEventListener()`, the value of `this` inside the handler is a reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the `currentTarget` property of the event argument that is passed to the handler.

So `var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;` is fine, but the reason for it not working are your syntax errors. Those `(` in front of the `var audio =`

This error should in the console of your browser as an error like this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'